# Passing nullable(of integer) to sub or function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, integer, nullable

I have this code:

```
   Dim iwidth As Integer? = 125
   Dim iheight As Integer? = 45
   Recs.Add(New With {Key .URLSmallPic = "/EditorImage/BBM4.jpg", Key .URL = "#", Key .Width = iwidth, Key .Height = iheight})
```

Recs is a List variable.
The third and fourth parameter is nullable(of integer).
How to make single line of code, without declare iwidth and iheight variable?

Comment: My question is, why are you using an anonymous type there at all?  Why aren't you declaring a specific type for the purpose?

Comment: @jmcilhinney, thank u for your answer. I want to add a custom row to my Linq query result.

Comment: Does your LINQ query produce instances of a specific type or an anonymous type? If you want to be able to create instances of the same type in two different ways then it should be a specific named type.

Comment: The problem was solved by your answer @jmcilhinney. Thank u very much......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question as asked:

```
Recs.Add(New With {Key .URLSmallPic = "/EditorImage/BBM4.jpg",
                   Key .URL = "#",
                   Key .Width = New Nullable(Of Integer)(125),
                   Key .Height = New Nullable(Of Integer)(45)})
```

Comment: If Recs.Width is defined to be a nullable, do you actually need to do `New Nullable(Of Integer)(125)` or can you just do `125`?

Comment: @ProGrammer, there's no such thing as `Recs.Width`.  Read the question again.  `Recs` is a `List` - presumably a `List(Of Object)`.  The code is creating an instance of an anonymous type and adding it to that `List`.  The data types of the properties of that anonymous type are inferred from the values provided so, if you want `Width` and `Height` to be type `Integer?` then you have to provide values of that type.  If you provide an `Integer` then the data type of the property will be `Integer` too.

Comment: Ahh my mistake, but the question still stands. If you tried to pass 125 and read it as a nullable, would that work, or is it an autoconversion that would be prevented by Option Strict?

Comment: I guess it depends on the code that's reading the data.  I still don't really see that an anonymous type is appropriate here at all, which would make the question moot also. I've answered the question that was asked regardless of whether it was a misguided question in the first place.

Comment: Yeah they should definitely have a type, it was more just a curiosity of mine since I don't use nullables much, and you're possibly the best person to ask. Thanks :)

Comment: As an example, if the consuming code assumed a nullable type and tested the `HasValue` property then there would be trouble, while if it simply called `ToString` or assigned to another nullable variable then there'd be no issue.

Comment: _if the consuming code assumed a nullable type and tested the HasValue property_. Then creation of "predefined" class seems more proper way, which increase readability of list creation.

Comment: @Fabio, I agree, which is why I've recommended just that more than once. An answer is supposed to answer the questions asked though, so mine does.